# Declare a type, where that type is a func that returns a struct{}

Tags: go

I have this:

```
type HandlerCreator = func() struct{}
```

I am trying to declare a type, where the type is a `func` that returns a `struct{}` value.

so, yeah, a `HandlerCreator` might look like:

```
type Handler struct{}

func CreateHandler() Handler {
    return Handler{}
}
```

and I am trying to use that type in a map:

```
var Handlers = map[string]HandlerCreator{
    "Register": register.CreateHandler,  // <<<< compile error
}
```

but it says:

> cannot use register.CreateHandler (type func() register.Handler) as
>   type func() struct {} in map value

anyone know how to do this?

Golang won't even let me do this:

```
var Handlers = map[string]func(){
    "Register": register.CreateHandler,
}
```

I get this error:

```
cannot use register.CreateHandler (type func() register.Handler) as type func() in map value
```

again, CreateHandler is just a simple func, shown above.

Comment: go requires an explicit type, so even though `Handler` is `struct{}`, you cannot implicitly equate them. Why not make `type HandlerCreator = func() Handler`?

Comment: because HandlerCreator is a func that returns more than one kind of Handler

Comment: I could use `interface{}` but interface is not a callable (not a func)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say

```
type Handler struct{}
```

then the `Handler` type and an empty structure [are different types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions).  Therefore, a function returning `Handler` and a function returning `struct{}` are also of different types.

If I was doing it, I'd change the "creator" type to return the renamed return type

```
type HandlerCreator = func() Handler
```

but it should also work to change the function to return `struct{}`, or to change `Handler` to a [type alias](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Alias_declarations).

```
type Handler = struct{} // the "=" is important
```